# How to run bash script from npm script that exports environment variables

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, environment-variables, npm-scripts

I have a package.json that has the following script:

```
"scripts": {
  "config": ". ./setup.sh"
},
```

The setup.sh file prompts the user for an API token,

```
read -p "Enter API Authorization Token: " val
export API_AUTH_TOKEN=$val
```

and an environment via a PS3 menu. Ex: entering 1 should export DEFAULT_ENV='http://localhost:8000'.

And when I run this setup.sh via the terminal(. ./setup.sh), it works great. It's only when I run "npm run config", where it doesn't *actually* export those values, although it acts like it did. I'm under the impression this is related to this script being a process *within* the other process, and so, not affecting the global environment. How do I make it so that it does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because export only works in child processes and itself.

You can edit your file, adding the line to see it:

```
read -p "Enter API Authorization Token: " val
export API_AUTH_TOKEN=$val
echo $API_AUTH_TOEKEN
```

In fact it never affects the parent process (like the shell window)

To affect the global, you should save the variable in files like `.bashrc` and `source .bashrc` to make it into effect.